# Class and instance methods with the same name

Tags: objective-c

I'm looking at Apple's [MVC Networking sample project](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MVCNetworking/Introduction/Intro.html) and I have found that in the class `PhotoGallery` the author has created instance and class versions of the method `abandonGalleryCacheAtPath:`:

On line 139:

```
+ (void)abandonGalleryCacheAtPath:(NSString *)galleryCachePath
```

On line 457:

```
- (void)abandonGalleryCacheAtPath:(NSString *)galleryCachePath
```

All the instance version of the method seems to do is a bit of logging before calling the class method as follows:

```
[[QLog log] logWithFormat:@"gallery %zu abandon '%@'", (size_t) self.sequenceNumber, [galleryCachePath lastPathComponent]];
[[self class] abandonGalleryCacheAtPath:galleryCachePath];
```

The log message includes `self.sequenceNumber`, which is an instance variable which would not be available to the class method.

A couple of questions:

1. Will the system automatically direct calls to the right method e.g. if another **class** method calls `self abandonGalleryCacheAtPath:abc` then the class version of the method will be executed, and if another **instance** method calls it then the instance version of the method will be executed?
2. Do you think the author has implemented the instance method purely so that the value of `sequenceNumber` can be logged?  Are there any other design/technical benefits of doing this kind of double implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Objective C uses dynamic method binding, the system will automatically direct calls to the Class or Instance method depending on the context in which the call was made. Refer [Objective-C uses dynamic binding, but how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697093/objective-c-uses-dynamic-binding-but-how)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation - it answers my first question.  Do you have any thoughts about the second one?