# What is difference between dynamic binding Vs dynamic typing in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am having hard time to understand what is difference between dynamic binding Vs dynamic typing in Objective C. Can someone explain this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C uses dynamic binding, but how?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697093/objective-c-uses-dynamic-binding-but-how)

Comment: @Richard - Disagree. The OP's is asking about the difference between dynamic binding and dynamic typing. The question you referred to doesn't address dynamic typing at all.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[Dynamic typing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/DynamicTyping.html) in Objective-C means that the class of an object of type `id` is unknown at compile time, and instead is discovered at runtime when a message is sent to the object. For example, in the following code, the class of `foo` isn't known until we attempt to send the message `componentsSeparatedByString:`.

```
id foo = @"One Two Three";
NSArray *a = [foo componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

If instead of using the `id` data type we had done the following...

```
NSString *foo = @"One Two Three";
```

...then we'd be using *static typing* rather than dynamic typing.

[Dynamic binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/DynamicBinding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH15-SW1) means that the compiler doesn't know which method implementation will be selected; instead the method implementation is looked up at runtime when the message is sent. It basically helps us with [Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)). So

```
[foo description]
```

results in invoking a different method implementation if, for example, `foo` is an instance of `NSArray` rather than an instance of `NSString`.

Answer (score 7):

with dynamic typing you can have a variable of type id that can store any type of object. with dynamic binding you can do this: `id obj;   [obj doWhatever];` and as long as `obj` is of a type that implements `-(void)doWhatever` it will work.

Answer (score 4):

From Apple Documentation

***Dynamic typing***

A variable is dynamically typed when the type of the object it points to is not checked at compile time. Objective-C uses the id data type to represent a variable that is an object without specifying what sort of object it is. This is referred to as dynamic typing.

Dynamic typing contrasts with static typing, in which the system explicitly identifies the class to which an object belongs at compile time. Static type checking at compile time may ensure stricter data integrity, but in exchange for that integrity, dynamic typing gives your program much greater ***flexibility***. And through object introspection (for example, asking a dynamically typed, anonymous object what its class is), you can still verify the type of an object at runtime and thus validate its suitability for a particular operation.

The following example illustrates dynamic typing using a heterogeneous collection of objects:

```
NSArray *anArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A string", [NSDecimalNumber zero], [NSDate date], nil];
NSInteger index;
for (index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
    id anObject = [anArray objectAtIndex:index];
    NSLog(@"Object at index %d is %@", index, [anObject description]);
}
```

The object pointed to by the variable at runtime must be able to respond to whatever messages you send to it; otherwise, your program throws an exception. The actual implementation of the method invoked is determined using dynamic binding.

***Dynamic binding***

Dynamic binding is determining the method to invoke at runtime instead of at compile time. Dynamic binding is also referred to as late binding. In Objective-C, all methods are resolved dynamically at runtime. The exact code executed is determined by both the method name (the selector) and the receiving object.

Dynamic binding enables polymorphism. For example, consider a collection of objects including Dog, Athlete, and ComputerSimulation. Each object has its own implementation of a run method. In the following code fragment, the actual code that should be executed by the expression [anObject run] is determined at runtime. The runtime system uses the selector for the method run to identify the appropriate method in whatever the class of anObject turns out to be.

```
 NSArray *anArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:aDog, anAthlete, aComputerSimulation, nil];
id anObject = [anArray objectAtIndex:(random()/pow(2, 31)*3)];
[anObject run];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with Javascript, dynamic typing in objective C is pretty much similar to what 'var' is in Javascript, where the actual type of this variable will be figured out at run-time and once it's assigned.  It can be reused and retyped as many times as you like which makes it risky to use if you don't know the type of the object being held at the time of the execution as you as it could through 'unrecognized selector' run time exceptions. In Objective-C, all objects are of type id and therefore a variable of type id can be used for dynamic typing.

Dynamic Binding on objects is the 'polymorphic' behavior where the right method is called based on the type of object it's being called on at run time.

I hope that helps